# Spark 2.0: 4 Rows. IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying a super simple test program on Spark 2.0 on Amazon EMR 5.0:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as spark_functions

schema = StructType([
    StructField("cola", StringType()),
    StructField("colb", IntegerType()),
])

rows = [
    Row("alpha", 1),
    Row("beta", 2),
    Row("gamma", 3),
    Row("delta", 4)
]

data_frame = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema)

print("count={}".format(data_frame.count()))

data_frame.write.save("s3a://test3/test_data.parquet", mode="overwrite")

print("done")
```

Results in:

```
count=4
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o85.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:487)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.confChanged(LocalDirAllocator.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AOutputStream.<init>(S3AOutputStream.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:913)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:894)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:780)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:336)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.commitJob(WriterContainer.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:144)
    ... 29 more
(<class 'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError'>, Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while calling o85.save.\n', JavaObject id=o86), <traceback object at 0x7fa65dec5368>)
```

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue, and after a lot of messing about it appears s3:// and s3n:// work. But they are a lot slower than s3a:// ... The only way I could get s3a:// to work was by setting a buffer directory so it isn't doing the fast copy direct from memory -

```
hadoopConf=sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.buffer.dir", "/home/hadoop,/tmp")
```

It's unfortunately not much quicker than normal s3/s3n with that enabled however!

EDIT: Adding this also works to get rid of the error, realised I was assuming it was doing fast copy. Unfortunately no faster ... 
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.fast.upload", "true")

Comment: I can confirm that 
val hadoopConf=sc.hadoopConfiguration
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.fast.upload", "true") 
works but I haven't tested with large data sets.