# Spark. Simple "No space available in any of the local directories."

Tags: apache-spark

Here is a simple test program. This is obviously a tiny test data program.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as spark_functions

schema = StructType([
    StructField("cola", StringType()),
    StructField("colb", IntegerType()),
])

rows = [
    Row("alpha", 1),
    Row("beta", 2),
    Row("gamma", 3),
    Row("delta", 4)
]

data_frame = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema)

print("count={}".format(data_frame.count()))

data_frame.write.save("s3a://my-bucket/test_data.parquet", mode="overwrite")

print("done")
```

This fails with:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: No space available in any of the local directories.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:416)
```

This is running on Amazon EMR with S3 storage. There is plenty of disk space. Can anyone explain?

Comment: I submitted an answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282281/spark-2-0-4-rows-illegalargumentexception-bound-must-be-positive/39577314#39577314

Comment: Tried this code on Cloudera pyspark2 and works seamlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same error while using Spark 2.2 on EMR. The settings,  `fs.s3a.fast.upload=true` and `fs.s3a.buffer.dir="/home/hadoop,/tmp"` (or any other folder for that matter) did not help me. It seems like my issue was related to shuffle space.

I had to add `--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true` to my spark-submit / spark-shell to resolve this error.