# Zeppelin: No space available in any of the local directories

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I am saving dataframe in s3 using zeppelin notebook.

```
df=spark.sql("select * from person")
df.write.mode('overwrite').option("header", "true").csv("s3a://file/location/")
```

I am getting error in zeppelin output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-3486998044016857551.py", line 367, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-3486998044016857551.py", line 360, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 766, in csv
    self._jwrite.csv(path)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o454.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:435)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:471)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:597)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: No space available in any of the local directories.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.createTmpFileForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.createTmpFileForWrite(S3AFileSystem.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AOutputStream.<init>(S3AOutputStream.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:932)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:913)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.DirectFileOutputCommitter.commitJob(DirectFileOutputCommitter.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:207)
    ... 45 more
```

But when I checked `Spark UI`, the job finished successfully. Then I checked the `S3 console`, the data was written there.

And when i am running same code with `pyspark console`, its running successfully.

Please help me resolve this issue with zeppelin.

I have checked other [links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51717600/5019163) too which didnt helped

**Edits:**

> Solution: On changing url from s3a to s3, its working properly. Please
>   help me with the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it failed while creating the zero byte `_SUCCESS` marker.

1. If a job doesn't have that marker, you can never be sure that the job completed successfully; something may have gone wrong.
2. If you don't have space for the temp file created during temporary creation (256K), then that specific machine is in trouble.

Anyway: it's moot.

## Due to the eventual consistency of S3 you cannot safely use S3 as a direct destination of work committed through `FileOutputCommitter` without a consistency layer.

For AWS EMR, that's "consistent EMR", for S3A that's S3Guard, or even better, use the S3A committers in Hadoop 3.1.

Without these, everything may appear to work, but every so often, inconsistent listings in S3 will cause data created by one of the workers to get missed, resulting in less data in the final results than expected *and nothing will be reported, as nothing has noticed this*

I'm not making this up. Go look at [HADOOP-13345](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13345) [HADOOP-13786](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13786) and [A Zero-Rename Committer](https://github.com/steveloughran/zero-rename-committer/releases/download/tag_draft_003/a_zero_rename_committer.pdf) if you want to know the details.